# How to set "Deprecated" to kotlin class and ignore error?

Tags: android

In Android Studio, I have some classes written in Kotlin that I use only for trivial purposes, and they have a lot of compilation errors, I want to keep them, not compile, and studio doesn't report errors.
How to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just comment it?

Comment: I assume you don't want to delete them just in case you might need them or want to refer to them at some point in the future? If that's the case then you can use version control to commit them to a repository and then delete them from your current codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Move these classes to another module and do not add to the application gradle.